# regex not working as expected when matching file names with wildcards

Tags: php, regex, wildcard

I am writing a PHP function that takes an array of file names and removes file names from the array if they do not match a set of criteria input by the user. The function iterates through the array and compares each value to a regex. The regex is formed by inserting variables from user input. If the user didn't specify a variable, regex wildcard characters are inserted in the variable's place. The file names are all very systematic, like `2020-06-N-1.txt` so I know exactly how many characters to expect in the file names and from the user input. However, when I run the code, file names that don't match the regex are still in the array. Some non-matching file names are taken out, but many others are left in. Parts of my PHP code are below. Any help is appreciated.

```
function fileFilter() {
    global $fileArray, $fileFilterPattern;
    
    /* The loop starts at 2 and goes to count()-1 because the first 2 elements were removed 
earlier with unset */
    for ($j = 2; $j < count($fileArray) - 1; $j++) {
        if(!(preg_match($fileFilterPattern, $fileArray[$j]))) {
            unset($fileArray[$j]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

// If user does not provide a filter value, it gets converted into wildcard symbol
if ($month == '') {
    $month = '..';
}
if ($year == '') {
    $year = '....';
}
if ($section == '') {
    $section = '.';
}

$fileFilterPattern = "/{$year}-{$month}-{$section}-.\.txt/";

/* function only runs if user applied at least one filter */
if (!($month == '..' && $year == '....' && $section == '.')) {
    fileFilter();
}
```

Below I have included an example of how the array contains elements that aren't matches. I obtain my output array using `echo json_encode($fileArray);`

My input:
month is `""`
year is `""`
section is `"L"`

Expected result:
Array contains only files that have L in the section spot (`YEAR-MONTH-**SECTION**-NUMBER.txt`)

Resulting array:

```
{"8":"2020-06-L-1.txt","9":"2020-06-L-2.txt","10":"2020-06-L-3.txt","11":"2020-06-L-4.txt","12":"2020-06-L-5.txt","15":"2020-06-N-3.txt","16":"2020-06-N-4.txt","17":"2020-06-N-5.txt","18":"2020-06-N-6.txt","19":"2020-06-O-1.txt","20":"2020-06-O-2.txt","21":"2020-06-O-3.txt","22":"2020-06-O-4.txt","23":"2020-06-S-1.txt","24":"2020-06-S-2.txt","25":"2020-06-S-3.txt"}
```

Comment: Do you need the forward slash `/` at the end of `$fileFilterPattern`?

Comment: What types of file names does it match that you think it SHOULDN'T match?

Comment: @devduder I tried removing the ending forward slash. The resulting array got even weirder...

Comment: @AbraCadaver I will update my question with some examples now!

Comment: Also, it only runs if one of the filters is supplied by the user, so what is an example of one of those and file names that it shouldn't match?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I updated my question with an example. Let me know if it still isn't clear and I can add more

Comment: You need to show an echo of the filter variables and where they come from, it works https://3v4l.org/0hejr

Comment: @AbraCadaver It must have been something with the for loop that was messing everything up! I changed over to a foreach loop and everything works like a charm. Thank you so much! This has been bugging me all day!

Comment: Actually it was probably the `count($fileArray)` in the loop condition.  Do `$count = count($fileArray);` before the loop and check `$count` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using unset() inside a loop.  On the next iteration, the index is no longer the same as it was before you messed with the array using unset().  Sometimes, you deal with this by using array_values(), but in this case it's simpler to just build a second array that has only the values you want.  The following code works.  I've used array_values() just to take the string that you provided and get the indexes back to normal.

That said, since the "*first 2 elements were removed 
earlier with unset*" you need to run array_values() on the array before you get to this part.

```
<?php

$str ='{"8":"2020-06-L-1.txt","9":"2020-06-L-2.txt","10":"2020-06-L-3.txt","11":"2020-06-L-4.txt","12":"2020-06-L-5.txt","15":"2020-06-N-3.txt","16":"2020-06-N-4.txt","17":"2020-06-N-5.txt","18":"2020-06-N-6.txt","19":"2020-06-O-1.txt","20":"2020-06-O-2.txt","21":"2020-06-O-3.txt","22":"2020-06-O-4.txt","23":"2020-06-S-1.txt","24":"2020-06-S-2.txt","25":"2020-06-S-3.txt"}';

$fileArray = json_decode($str, true);
$fileArray = array_values($fileArray);

echo '<p>fileArray: ';
var_dump($fileArray);
echo '</p>';

function fileFilter() {
    global $fileArray, $fileFilterPattern;
    $filteredArray = [];

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($fileArray); $j++) {
        if(preg_match($fileFilterPattern, $fileArray[$j]) === 1) {
            //unset($fileArray[$j]);
            array_push($filteredArray, $fileArray[$j]);
        }
    }
    echo '<p>filteredArray: ';
    var_dump($filteredArray);
    echo '</p>';
    //return;
}

$month =='';
$year = '';
// If user does not provide a filter value, it gets converted into wildcard symbol
if ($month == '') {
    $month = '..';
}
if ($year == '') {
    $year = '....';
}
if ($section == '') {
    $section = '.';
}

$section = 'L';

$fileFilterPattern = "#{$year}-{$month}-{$section}-.\.txt#";

echo '<p>fileFilterPattern: ';
var_dump($fileFilterPattern);
echo '</p>';

/* function only runs if user applied at least one filter */
if (!($month == '..' && $year == '....' && $section == '.')) {
    fileFilter();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the `count` decreases each time you `unset`, so you should define the count once.  Assuming the `-1` and `$j = 2` are correct for your scenario:

```
$count = count($fileArray) - 1;

for ($j = 2; $j < $count; $j++) {
    if(!(preg_match($fileFilterPattern, $fileArray[$j]))) {
        unset($fileArray[$j]);
    }
}
```

There are others ways where you don't have to assume and then keep track of the keys:

```
foreach($fileArray as $k => $v) {
    if(!preg_match($fileFilterPattern, $v)) {
        unset($fileArray[$k]);
    }
}
```

I would get rid of your `fileFilter` function and use this handy function instead, which will return all items that match the pattern:

```
$fileArray = preg_grep($fileFilterPattern, $fileArray);
```